# How can I make a video as a full page background?

Tags: html, css, video

I like the way the folks at http://chopdawgstudios.com/ made there homepage that seems to render a video in the background.  How can I create something similar? Is there something like background-video for it?

Comment: [jquery.videoBG plugin](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/)

Comment: Did you study their source code? What did you learn from it?

Comment: @floris it seems that they have a few videos that they begin playing as auto-play.  And they seem to be included in the body and I guess they are using js to adjust to the width of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a CSS issue, it's javascript. There's plenty of scripts to do this. Here are a couple:

http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/
http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/

Answer (score 0):

It is a HTML 5 video tag. You can place the video tag any where. I noticed www.bing.com always use this technique as well.